# Undeclared - 'first use in function'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, function, methods

I'm new to Objective-C, though I have a very good hand in Android. I'm trying to make a call to a method but it gives me 'first use in function'. I know I'm making a silly mistake but experts could figure it out easily.

**RootViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ContentViewController.h"

@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {
    ContentViewController *contentViewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) ContentViewController *contentViewController;

- (NSString*)getContentFileName:(NSString*)title; //<--- This function declartion

@end
```

**RootViewController.m**

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "HAWATAppDelegate.h"
#import "ContentViewController.h"

@implementation RootViewController
@synthesize contentViewController;

...
more methods
...

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    HAWATAppDelegate *appDelegate = (HAWATAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSString *title = (NSString *) [appDelegate.titles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *fileName = getContentFileName:title; //<--- Here is the error

    ...
}

- (NSString*) getContentFileName:(NSString*)title {
    return [title lowercaseString];
}

@end
```

There must be a simple thing I'm missing. Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*OMG!!* That should be `[self getContentFileName:title];`

Comment: Wow! Thanks @EmptyStack. Works now. Will accept your answer in 12 minutes ;)

Comment: OOOOMMMMGGGG, winner winner chicken dinner.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the method wrong. Calling methods in Objective-C is in the form:

```
[object selectorWithArgument:foo bar:baz];
```

So the line with the error should be:

```
NSString *fileName = [self getContentFileName:title]; //<--- Here is the error
```